# Compiling C program with libmongoc-1.0

Tags: c, mongodb, pkg-config

I cannot compile a program using the mongodb c driver.  I am using the CodeBlocks IDE.

In Build options-> Other Compiler Options, I have: `pkg-config  --libs --cflags libmongoc-1.0`
This produces an error: mongoc.h, no such file or directory.

The documentation shows: $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libmongoc-1.0)
This produces an error if placed in Build Options -> Other Compiler Options.
Error: expected ")"

Please advise.

Comment: Do "Other Compiler Options" need to be actual options? Run the command you pasted in there in your shell and put its output into your ide.

Comment: running "$(pkg-config --libs --cflags libmongoc-1.0" in terminal outputs:
Package libmongoc-1.0-0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libmongoc-1.0-0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libmongoc-1.0-0' found

The package is installed. Running "apt-get install libmongoc-1.0-0: returns:
libmongoc-1.0-0 is already the newest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on another post, here: [Problem installing Mongo C Driver on ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116733/problem-installing-mongo-c-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Basically, you need to also install the dev package, the documentation doesn't mention that.

Comment: What documentation exactly?

Comment: That page mentions dev packages.

Comment: Searching for "libmongoc-dev" on that page returns no results. That package was required.